# Angular material slider how to set ticks values

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, slider, angular-material, uislider

is there a way using angular slider to define sliding values for example if we have the min val 0 and max val 15 is it possible to set up the values that user can slide to from a list [3,4,6,9...] instead of having steps of 1 or 2?
If it's not possible with Angular material slider is there any other Angular module that can be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do that using Angular slide using `stepsArray: [3,4,6,9...]` here is [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/BkYhoLGtk0YIxVlCiZ59?p=preview) for that